# Mathematic doesn't compute absolute value of difference of solution of ODE from two different numerical methods

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, list-manipulation

While trying to compare the solution to an ODE by 2 different numerical methods Mathematica gives a wrong result.

More specifically I have te code.

```
n = 100;
u[0] = 0;
u[n + 1] = 0;
b = 10;
h = (b)/(n + 1);
x[i_] := i h
eqs = Table[(u[i + 1] - 2*u[i] + u[i - 1])/(h)^2 + u[i] == 
    E^-(x[i])^2, {i, 1, n}];


sol = Solve[eqs] // Flatten;
t = Table[{x[i], u[i]} /. sol, {i, 0, n + 1}];
solInt = Interpolation[t];


listplot = ListPlot[t];

uND = NDSolveValue[{und[0] == 0, und[10] == 0, 
   und''[x] + und[x] == E^-x^2}, und, {x, 0, 100}]

table = Table[{x[i], N[Abs[uND[x[i]] - solInt[x[i]]]]}, {i, 0, 101}];

TableForm[table]
table // ListPlot
```

I am using NDSolveValue and another numerical scheme, but when trying to compute some values $|u_{ND}(x(i))-solInt(x(i))|$ on a Table (where $u_{ND}(x(i))$ is the solution that NDSolveValue gives at points $x(i)$ and $solInt(x(i))$ is the solution for a numerical scheme I am using evaluated at points $x(i)$), Mathematica does not compute $|u_{ND}(x(i))-solInt(x(i))|$, instead it seems that it just computes $|u_{ND}(x(i))|$.

Why is this happeining?

Comment: What does `Table[N@solInt[x[i]], {i, 0, 101}]` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sol = NSolve[eqs] // Flatten` instead of `sol = Solve[eqs] // Flatten`.

The expressions in `Solve[eqs]` are too long to show, but for `sol = Solve[eqs] // Flatten`, this shows there's a problem:

```
sol[[3]] // N
```

> General::munfl: -(100/(40501536281489165478112409656048168989286509130<<307>>684352649030948910689327201023335532299769699899)) is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.
>
> ```
> (*  u[3.] -> 0.  *)
> ```

It strongly suggests that the solution in terms of exact rationals and the exponential function has terms/factors that underflow.

There are other ways to avoid the problem.  For instance, make `h` a float: `h = (b)/(n + 1.)`.  Basically, if you start with machine reals (or arbitrary precision), things should go fine.

---

*Addendum: Something extra*

This does the same thing as using `NSolve` (the `[[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]]` removes `u[0]` and `u[n+1]` from the linear system and tacitly assumes those boundary values are zero):

```
d2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[2,
    xgrid = Array[x, n + 2, 0],
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2];

usol2 = Join[
   {N@u[0]},
   LinearSolve[
    N@d2["DifferentiationMatrix"][[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]] + 
     IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray],
    E^-(xgrid[[2 ;; -2]])^2
    ],
   {N@u[n + 1]}];
usol2 == Table[u[i] /. sol, {i, 0, n + 1}]

(*  True  *)
```

`d2["DifferentiationMatrix"][[2 ;; -2]] // Normal` shows the coefficients `{1, -2, 1} / h^2`. The first and last rows use a different formula for the second derivative, but they're not needed because of the boundary conditions.